# Insert Html with JS

Tags: javascript

I need to insert `div_A` into `div_B`, but still keep `div_A` for reference ?

```js
var div_A = document.createElement('div');

var newdiv = `<div class="div_B"> ${div_A.outerHTML} </div>`;

$('.container').append(newdiv);  

div_A.append('Hello');
```

```css
.container{
  background-color:blue;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
.div_B{
 background-color:red;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}
.div_B div{
 background-color:yellow;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container"></div>
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: So do not use it as a string which defeats the purpose of the reference

Comment: I don't understand the downvote to this question. The user added his approach and minimal reproducible code. The user posted the question because he is stuck and wants to learn/understand something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than concatenating an HTML string, have the new `div_B` element be an actual element too, not just a string:

```js
var div_A = document.createElement('div');

var newdiv = $(`<div class="div_B" />`);
newdiv.append(div_A);

$('.container').append(newdiv);  

div_A.append('Hello');
```

```css
.container{
  background-color:blue;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
.div_B{
 background-color:red;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}
.div_B div{
 background-color:yellow;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: What if I want to insert `div_A`  into a div that is nested inside `div_B`?

Comment: Then you would do the same sort of thing - explicitly create each element you want, and append children to them while keeping a reference to the children.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the reference to the div update the content, you will need to append the element and not use the HTML of the element. The string is a snapshot at that time. It will not do anything magical and keep updating.

So create the div, append the div, and now you can update it.

```js
var div_A = document.createElement('div');

var newdiv = $('<div class="div_B"></div>');
newdiv.append(div_A);

$('.container').append(newdiv);  

div_A.append('Hello');
```

```css
.container{
  background-color:blue;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
.div_B{
 background-color:red;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}
.div_B div{
 background-color:yellow;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I need to insert `div_A` into a div that is nested inside `div_B`?

Answer (score 0):

need to use somthing like this

```
var divb = document.createElement("div")
divb.InnerHtml = diva.OuterHtml

container.appendChild(divb)
```